# What is the difference between (int *i) and (int* i) in context of both C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I find that some forums tell these are different in nature.
the outputs obtained are though similar

Comment: There is no difference, except aesthetically.

Comment: Just be careful for this case: `int* p,q;` is equal to `int *p, q;` (i.e. `int *p; int q;`), but not `int *p, *q;`

Answer (score 6):

In C and C++

```
int *i;
int*i;
int* i;
```

All are same.

Comment: Same for C++ as well.