# C pointers, int* val vs int *val

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

Im recently started to learn C but there is one thing that keeps confusing me about pointers.

I know that pointers reference to the adress of memory, but what is the diffrence between int* val and int *val, doesn't this all reference to val?

or else why would want to reference the type?

Comment: There is no difference, it's just code formatting style.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28260445/what-is-the-difference-between-int-i-and-int-i-in-context-of-both-c-and-c/28260455#28260455